# Double Integration Change of Variables

Tags: multiple-integral

Evaluate $\int\int xy \, dx\,dy$ over the square with corners $(0,0), (1,1), (2,0),$ and $(1,−1)$ using

$x$=$\frac{u+v}{2}$

$y$=$\frac{u-v}{2}$

In my transformation, I get the limits for $v$ as $u-1$ to $u$ and $u$ as $0$ to $2$.
But these limits are incorrect.
The solution the book provides is zero but my evaluation leads to $\frac{1}{3}$

I computed the Jacobian and got the determinant equal to $\frac{1}{2}$

After transformation the integral I get is:

$\int_0^2 \int_{u-2}^{u}  \frac{u^2-v^2}{8} \, dvdu$

But somehow the solution to the integral that is $\frac{1}{3}$ does not agree with the solution provided to me i.e. zero.
Are my limits to the new integral incorrect or is my Jacobian wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your limiting values are incorrect.

If you convert the corners of the square to the new coordinate system, you see that:

- $(0, 0)$ maps to $(0, 0)$
- $(1, 1)$ maps to $(2, 0)$
- $(2, 0)$ maps to $(2, 2)$
- $(1, -1)$ maps to $(0, 2)$

So the boundaries are just $0$ to $2$, for both $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a mistake in the question!I'm really sorry!

Comment: I see. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: So v should range from -2 to 2? Isn't v a function of u?

Comment: No, they both range from $0$ to $2$, and neither is a function of the other. If you draw the $u$ and $v$-axes on a graph, this will be much clearer. Essentially, we're turning the axes so the square is nicely aligned. We do scale the square in the process, which is why the Jacobian is not equal to 1.

Comment: Oh my bad...I got the (1,-1) equated incorrectly...Thanks a lot...I got it now...